# save save text in a txtfield, does not work?

Tags: javascript, css, html

How can i save text in a text box?

when i reload the page, the text the box will be deleted.

i have tried this.

`<td align='left' bgcolor='#cfcfcf'><input type="text" name="txtfield" value="" placeholder="input your text" localstorage.setitem(name) /></td>`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you save the value some where? For late use.

Comment: Does local storage really work in the element attributes like that?  That just looks like an HTML syntax error...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>


<td align='left' bgcolor='#cfcfcf'>
<input type="text" name="txtfield" id="txtfield" value="" 
placeholder="input your text"  onchange="storeitem(this.value)"/>
</td>

<script language="javascript">
function storeitem(val){
    localStorage.setItem('txtfield', val)
}

function loaditem(){

    var txtfield = document.getElementById('txtfield');
    txtfield.value = localStorage.getItem('txtfield');

}

window.onload = loaditem;
</script>
</body>

</html>
```